# Python Panda count occurences depending on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have added the x,y coordinate of my cars into a panda. I would like to be able to count how many cars are in a certain area. In this case I would like to get the count of all cars in x = 2 and y=1 to 3. I would like to get the count 2 since there is no car in location (2,2). I'm not that used to pandas yet so I want to loop everything.

```
def index_used_x_y(x,y):
    try:
        cars .loc[(cars ['x'] == x) & (cars ['y'] == y)].index
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

cars = pd.DataFrame()
cars ['x'] = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4])
cars ['y'] = np.array([1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,3])

count_cars = 0
print(cars )

x_from = 2
x_to = 2
y_from = 1
y_to = 3

for x in range(x_from,x_to+1):
    for y in range(y_from,y_to+1):
        if  index_used_x_y(x,y):
            count_cars +=1

print(count_cars )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you mention you'd like to use a loop, but the power of Pandas is to avoid loops (at least loops in plain Python: under the (Pandas) hood, there are loops implemented).

You could use the following:

```
import pandas as pd
 
cars = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],
                     'y': [1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]})
count = ( (cars['x'] == 2) & ((cars['y'] >= 1) | (cars['y'] <= 3)) ).sum()
print(count)
```

The logic here is in the comparisons, which are combined through boolean logic. You will need to pay attention to the parentheses, otherwise things will mess up: `y >= 1` *or*ed with `y <= 3`, and that results is then *and*ed with `x == 2`.

The intermediate series, before summing it, is then the following:

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4      True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
dtype: bool
```

and the `.sum()` method will interpret `True` as 1, and `False` as 0, resulting in a total of 2.

Comment: Thank you soo much. WOW, it took you less then 10 minutes to answer! And it works very well. It would probably have taken me hours to figure this one out myself, thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html)**:

```
(cars['x'].between(x_from,x_to) & cars['y'].between(y_from,y_to)).sum()
```

---

```
2
```

Comment: Thank you, this works very well too. I am starting to learn just how much you can do with Python.